# A urine test, the VMA test

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

Neuroblastoma is a rare, serious, but treatable disease. A urine test, the VMA test, has been developed that gives a positive diagnosis in about 70 % of cases of neuroblastoma. It has been proposed that this test be used for large-scale screening of children. Assume 300,000 children are to be tested, of whom 8 have the disease. We are interested in whether or not the test detects the disease in the 8 children who have the disease.

Find the probability that

a) all eight cases will be detected

I have calculated that $1 \cdot (0,7)^{8} \cdot (1 - 0,7)^{0} = 5.8  \% $

b) only one case will be missed

And here I have  $8 \cdot (0,7)^{7} \cdot (1 - 0,7)^{1} = 19.8  \% $

c) two or more cases will  be missed

But how should I calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Is there another possibility to

1. all eight cases will be detected ;
2. only one case will be missed ;
3. two or more cases will be missed ?

Comment: Are you maybe thinking about that c) can be calculated if I add a) and b) together

Comment: @Alim Teacher Hum... Not really. If there is only $3$ different possible events $A ,B, C$ to something, what's the probability that $A$ **or** $B$ **or** $C$ will happen ? (No trap in this question).

Comment: Okay A=5.8 % B=19.8 % and C will be C=74.5 %